# The LSUIElement key in Info.plist is being ignored (AvaloniaUI, net7.0-macos)

Tags: .net, macos, info.plist, dock, avaloniaui

Currently, I am trying to create a cross-platform app with Avalonia. One criterion of the app is that it should run in the background without a Dock icon. When I publish the MacOS project with the TFM `net7.0-macos` and create a .app bundle from it, I encounter an issue where the `LSUIElement` key in `Info.plist` is ignored when the app starts. All other keys have an effect; for example, the app's name is displayed as defined in `Info.plist` and not as set in app.axaml. The `LSUIPresentationMode` key also has an effect, so it's not a problem with the `Info.plist` being faulty or not loaded.

Here is the content of the Info.plist:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>car.icns</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.identifier</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>NameFromPList</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0.0</string>
    <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
    <string>10.12</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>Plist.Desktop</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Test</string>
    <key>LSUIElement</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>NSApplication</string>
    <key>DTPlatformName</key>
    <string>macosx</string>
    <key>DTXcode</key>
    <string>1500</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And [here](https://github.com/Irasil/AvaloniaPListTest) is the link to the test repository:

I have already tried setting `LSUIElement` as a `string` to `1` or as a `Boolean` to `true` by default. Additionally, I am looking for other ways to hide the Dock icon.

I am grateful for any assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avalonia Native partially overrides the Info.plist, so it resets the values on startup [Avalonia Native](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/0c4f372410d0f45c814930da84c73f65b377176b/src/Avalonia.Native/AvaloniaNativePlatformExtensions.cs#L87C5-L91C1).

This can be bypassed by setting this value to false. This is achieved by adding this value to the AppBuilder.

```cs
class Program {
    // Initialization code. Don't use any Avalonia, third-party APIs or any
    // SynchronizationContext-reliant code before AppMain is called: things aren't initialized
    // yet and stuff might break.
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args) => BuildAvaloniaApp()
        .StartWithClassicDesktopLifetime(args);

    // Avalonia configuration, don't remove; also used by visual designer.
    public static AppBuilder BuildAvaloniaApp()
        => AppBuilder.Configure<App>()
            .UsePlatformDetect()
            .WithInterFont()
            .LogToTrace()
            .UseReactiveUI()
            .With(new MacOSPlatformOptions() { ShowInDock = false});
}
```